# What happens with re-entry at different angles?

Tags: reentry

I was reading the [article on J002E3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J002E3), and it mentions that most other S-IVB have entered the atmosphere and mostly burned until reduced to relatively small pieces. They did, however, enter the atmosphere with less energy than J002E3 would have coming from a Solar orbit and (I assume) entered on more or less tangential trajectories.

The question is, would such a stage of a rocket burn more or less, if it were to enter  head-on into the atmosphere?

Comment: The steeper the entry, the higher the peak heating, but the shorter the heating period. I believe something like an S-IVB stage would burn completely regardless of entry angle.